# Mysql query for ( full text)searching with multiple order by conditions

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have following tables:

```
    user
user_id | name
1          W
2          x
3          Y
4          Z

    author
auth_id | name
1          M
2          N
3          O
4          P

    preferred_author
user_id | auth_id
1          2
1          3
1          4
2          1

    book
book_id | title
1          Hello world 01
2          Hello world 02
3          Hello world 03
4          Hello world 04
5          Hello world 

  book_author
book_id | auth_id
1          2
2          3
3          4
4          1
```

Now when a user `W` searches for a book named `hello world` i want show the books which are by user's preferred author, first and then the other results according to relevance. What I tried was `selecting all the ids of preferred authors and saved in a php array`

```
PHP:
Say, $p_auth_ids = (2, 3, 4);
```

Then i ran a query for searching:

```
$query = "SELECT b.book_id, b.title, 
MATCH(b.title) AGAINST("hello world" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance 
FROM book AS b 
INNER JOIN book_author AS ba ON b.book_id=ba.book_id
WHERE ba.auth_id IN ('".$p_auth_ids."') 
AND 
MATCH(b.title) AGAINST("hello world" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY relevance DESC"
```

Output should be:

```
book_id | title

1          Hello world 01
2          Hello world 02
3          Hello world 03
5          Hello world 
4          Hello world 04
```

Did not work. So what should be the query for what i want? Thanks.

Comment: *Did not work* is not an error description. Descripe what is not working, wrong result or an error message?

Comment: Order is not correct @Jens

Comment: expected result added @Jens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this query will give you what you want. It JOINs the `book` table to the `preferred_author` (via `book_author`) and then to the `user` table. In the `JOIN` to `user`, we add the `user.name = 'W'` condition so that only that user's preferred authors have a non-null `user_id` in the result set. Then we can order on `user_id IS NULL` (which will evaluate to 0 for books by the user's preferred authors and 1 otherwise) followed by `relevance DESC`:

```
SELECT b.book_id, b.title, MATCH(b.title) AGAINST("hello world" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance 
FROM book b
LEFT JOIN book_author ba ON ba.book_id = b.book_id
LEFT JOIN preferred_author pa ON pa.auth_id = ba.auth_id
LEFT JOIN user u ON pa.user_id = u.user_id AND u.name = 'W'
ORDER BY u.user_id IS NULL, relevance DESC
```

Output (note that all your titles are too similar to generate different relevance values so it doesn't sort exactly as you specified, but if you change the titles in the demo you will see it working):

```
book_id     title           relevance
1           Hello world 01  0.000000003771856604828372
2           Hello world 02  0.000000003771856604828372
3           Hello world 03  0.000000003771856604828372
4           Hello world 04  0.000000003771856604828372
5           Hello world     0.000000003771856604828372
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2461b52bf93da906d9d6cc4f8f75e910)